# Python Pandas : Pivot groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame looks like this;

```
Name,Comp,Dept,Salary,Allowance
Sam,Google,Sales,10000,4500
Sandra,Google,Sales,2300,3450
Allan,Google,Sales,2400,1000
Helen,Google,Mktg,3456,700
Rick,Google,Mktg,5412,352
Farrow,Apple,Sales,9786,190
Isaac,Apple,Sales,4500,230
Tim,Apple,Mktg,4500,500
Ben,Apple,Mktg,3490,450
Julie,Apple,Mktg,4590,750
```

I would like to get 2 outputs in the following format;

**Output 1:** - This is the mean of Salary by dept for the 2 companies

```
Dept    Google  Apple
Sales   4900    7143
Mktg    4434    4193
```

**Output 2** - This is the value of the maximum paid person by dept for 'Apple' & 'Google'

```
Dept    Google  Apple
Sales   10000   9786
Mktg    5412    4590
```

I've reached so far;

```
data.groupby(['Dept','Comp'])['Salary'].mean().order(ascending=False)

Dept   Comp  
Sales  Apple     7143.000000
       Google    4900.000000
Mktg   Google    4434.000000
       Apple     4193.333333
Name: Salary, dtype: float64
```

How do I pivot the results to get the formats mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unstack`.

```
In [111]: means = df.groupby(['Comp', 'Dept'])['Salary'].mean()

In [112]: means.unstack(0).sort(ascending=False)
Out[112]: 
Comp         Apple  Google
Dept                      
Sales  7143.000000    4900
Mktg   4193.333333    4434

[2 rows x 2 columns]

In [110]: df.groupby(['Comp', 'Dept'])['Salary'].max().unstack(0).sort(ascending=False)
Out[110]: 
Comp   Apple  Google
Dept                
Sales   9786   10000
Mktg    4590    5412

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```